# How can I make default route in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to make default route in my routes.js file using [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) package.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Router, Redirect, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import MainContainer from './containers/main';

const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={MainContainer} />
            <Redirect from='/' exact to='/main'/>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

But it doesn't redirect `/` to `/main`. Basically, whenever user goes to `/` it should redirect to `/main`. Also, the `/main` should be starting point (homepage) when I build my app. I am using [create-react-app boilerplate CLI](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the effect that you want, you should, first of all, move the **Redirect** to the top of the **Switch**.

Second, you have to change the "to" property for your **Route** to `/main`. Since that is the location that you want to load your **MainContainer** component for.

Like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Router, Redirect, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import MainContainer from './containers/main';

const Routes = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from='/' to='/main'/>
            <Route path='/main' component={MainContainer} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

In the code you posted, all locations go to the **Route** component because they all contain `/`. So the switch will never hit the **Redirect**.

In my example, the **Redirect** will get hit when the location is exactly `/`. It will then redirect the user to `/main`, where the **Switch** will hit the **Route** which loads your **MainContainer** component.

Comment: Thanks, I was close. :)
Is there a better way, with using `history`?

Comment: This way is perfect if all you want to do is change the 'default' location from `/` to `/main`. Using history for this is possible, but it will make the project more complicated then this solution does.